Does the group of automorphisms $f$ of the field of complex numbers for which $f(i)=i$ have trivial center?
Let $G$ be the group of automorphisms of the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. Then, while the identity and complex conjugation are two obvious elements of $G$, there are also others (known as wild automorphisms), assuming the axiom of choice.
Also, let $H \triangleleft G$ be the subgroup of those automorphisms $f$ for which $f(i)=i$ (which has index $2$, and thus is normal).
Then, the center of $G$ is trivial, as the only automorphisms that commute with complex conjugation are the identity and complex conjugation. Indeed, if $f$ commutes with complex conjugation, then $f$ must restrict to an automorphism of the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ (as the real numbers are exactly the complex numbers that are their own conjugates), but the only automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ is the identity, so $f$ must fix $\mathbb{R}$, which means that it must be either the identity or complex conjugation. So, if $\mathrm{id} \ne f \in Z(G)$, then either $f$ is complex conjugation (in which case it does not commute with any wild automorphism, contradicting $f \in Z(G)$) or it is a wild automorphism (in which case it does not commute with complex conjugation, again contradicting $f \in Z(G)$).
But is the center of the index-$2$ subgroup $H$ also trivial?
Perhaps, that could be proven using a transcendence basis of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ or over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ (the algebraic numbers). If an automorphism $f$ fixing the algebraic numbers has $f(T)=T$ for some transcendence basis $T$ of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, then any bijection $T \to T$ that does not commute with the restriction of $f$ to $T$ could be extended to an automorphism (still fixing the algebraic numbers) that does not commute with $f$. But an automorphism fixing $i$ need not map a transcendence basis to itself, nor does it need to restrict to the identity on the algebraic numbers (e.g., it could map $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$), so the result is not obvious.
Alternatively, that could instead be proven using the fact that $G$ is the semidirect product $H \rtimes \{\mathrm{id}, z \mapsto \bar{z}\}$.  But a semidirect product, in general, could have trivial center even if the two factors are abelian (or at least have nontrivial centers), so I do not see how that could help.

Your argument that complex conjugation is in the center is not correct; you assumed implicitly that $f$ preserves $\mathbb{R}$, but none of the wild automorphisms do that.

@QiaochuYuan Yes, it was my mistake. I have now realized that complex conjugation actually only commutes with itself and the identity, which immediately makes the center of $G$ trivial. A more interesting problem (which I have just added) is to instead ask whether the subgroup of automorphisms fixing $i$ has trivial center.
